# how to produce delay in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to produce delay in ruby?

I used sleep statement but it didn't give me what I want.

```
puts "amit"
sleep(10)
puts "scj"
```

I want it to first print amit, then a delay of 10 seconds, then print scj.

But in above case what happens is it will pause for 10 seconds and then it will print amit and scj together. I don't want that.

I hope you got what I want to say.

Comment: where are you running your script from?  Try running it from the command line instead of through SciTE or some other editor.

Comment: If i enter `puts 'bla'; sleep(10); puts '...and continue!'` in irb, it justs works. Please explain more what your context is. Platform, ruby-version, maybe a small example ...

Answer (score 11):

I can't reproduce this. From a console, this does exactly what you'd expect:

```
puts "amit"
sleep 10
puts "scj"
```

(Ruby 1.8.6 on Linux)

Can you provide a similar short but complete example which *doesn't* do what you want - or explain your context more?

If you're writing a web application, then the browser may well only see any data once the whole response has been written - that would explain what you're seeing. If that's the case, you'll need a different approach which would allow the initial response to be written first, and then make the browser make another request. The delay could be at the server or the client, depending no the scenario.

Comment: actully jon what i want is simple i want to get delay between two these two statement but using sleep what happening the programme execution starts from sleep statement itself that i don't want i want flow of execution start from puts"amit" and then i want 10 sec delay and final statement ... thats it i want

Answer (score 9):

Call `$stdout.flush` before the call to sleep. The output is probably buffered (although usually output is only line-buffered so `puts`, which produces a newline, should work without flushing, but apparently that's not true for your terminal).