# Producing delay between statements in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Again, I'm asking this question: How to produce delay in Ruby?

```
puts "amit"
sleep(10)
puts "asda"
```

I want a delay between two statements. When I tried the above example, first I have a delay of 10 seconds, and then both statements execute. I don't want that.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to produce delay in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084232/how-to-produce-delay-in-ruby). This question has already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow. Please try and search the site for existing questions before asking a new one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It's not like he would have had to search. That question (and at least one other duplicate) has been asked by the same person.

Answer (score 2):

looks like the puts statement writes the text to the output buffer, but 
doesn't flush it at the newline

try to add

```
$stdout.flush
```

after the print statements

your programm should look like this

```
puts "foo"
$stdout.flush
sleep(10)
puts "bar"
```

Comment: but sir if i use any statement like print than also works??
or how to produce delay between ruby not only between puts statement

Comment: The puts statement is called 10 second later but the operating system bufferes the output of the first statement until either you flush the buffer or the buffer is full

Comment: if you ask the operating system to print something on the screen or the terminal (by calling puts for example) it first stores the string into a buffer (for performance reasons) and writes the buffer to the screen if the buffer is full, or if your program tells it so by calling flush

Comment: but if i m writing simply puts "amit" then it simply print amit to screen without explicitly calling flush .is it means buffer is full??

Comment: if the program ends the buffer gets flushed automaticaly